# Tengo una duda con los servlets

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, jdbc

Hola que tal este es mi código que tengo pero no se como pasaría esto que tengo a un `servlet` la verdad no tengo idea y estoy sufriendo si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceré, por cierto ya tengo lo que es la conexión y eso solo me falta el `servelet`

```
 public void   Modifica (int estado, java.util.Date fechaHora,  java.util.Date fechaHoraultima, int id_publicacion)               
 {
  Connection connection = null;
  PreparedStatement prepareStmt = null;

  String query = "update publicaciones set estado,"
        + "fechaHora=?, "
        + "fechaHoraultima=GETDATE() "
        + "where id_publicacion = ? ";

  try{
      connection = getDBConnection();
      prepareStmt  = connection.prepareStatement(query);


      prepareStmt.setInt(1,estado);
      prepareStmt.setDate(2,fechaHora);
      prepareStmt.setDate(3,fechaHoraultima );
      prepareStmt.setInt(4,id_publicacion);
      prepareStmt.executeUpdate();

  } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Los Servlets son una clase cualquiera que extiende de [HttpServlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

Esta clase utiliza dos métodos principales para procesar el request: doGet y doPost.

Si tu código ya funciona entonces simplemente es pegarle en alguno de esos métodos los cuales se ejecutarán según tu request. Por ejemplo, si es desde un formulario HTML y quieres que se ejecute el método doPost hay que setear **POST** en el atributo **method** del form.

El response de los servlets varía según cómo lo quieras utilizar (una String de respuesta, una redirect, un mensaje formateado), ve la [documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).

[Aquí te dejo un ejemplo sencillo](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Ejemplo_sencillo_de_Servlet)

Para poder utilizar un servlet hay que [registrarlo](http://docs.roguewave.com/hydraexpress/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/3-7.html) en el web.xml de tu proyecto.:

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servletexample.createHelloWorldExample
      </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorldExample/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: vale muchas gracias